# Improve execution speed of python program to find two unknown variables with given result

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to improve the execution speed of a function to return two unknown variables of a math equation..

Given *ab(a+b)=n* with *n* known.

```
import math

def f(n):
  # ab(a+b)=n
  m = int(math.sqrt(n))
  r = range(2, m + 1)
  c = set()

  for i in r:
    a = i

    if n % a or a in c:
      continue

    while a < m:
      b = int((-math.pow(a,2) + math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 4) + 4 * a * n)) / (2 * a))

      if n == a * b * (a + b):
        return (a, b)

      c.add(a)
      a = a*2

  return (0,0)

print(f(102123161417560384731630000))
```

Maybe some of you know a way to improve the algorithm or is there a way to speed up the python execution.

My execution time right now is about 10 seconds, my target is < 3s.

Edit:
Forgot to mention, a and b are both positive integers.

Best regards.

Comment: do i understand correctly: you are looking for (positive?) integer solutions only?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist sorry forget to mention, yes. a & b are always positiv integer only.

Comment: you could try to factor `n`. your solution is some combination of 3 factors of n. not yet sure how to implement that...

Comment: I get a memory error when running your code, so I cannot really test it. However, the decorator 
`@numba.jint`
does wonders in speeding up algebraic codes. It works with (most) numpy objects, perhaps not math objects.

Comment: Your example n has suspiciously many/small factors. Is that true for all n you're interested in?

Comment: @KellyBundy I can not exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

i tried an approach using factoring and several [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/) methods.

unfortunately this is **way solwer** than what you did (for your given example). if `a` and `b` are both primes it might be more efficient than your solution.

i post it anyway. maybe you can come up with a way to improve on it:

```
from sympy.utilities.enumerative import factoring_visitor
from sympy.utilities.enumerative import multiset_partitions_taocp
from sympy import factorint


def solve(n):
    primes, multiplicities = zip(*factorint(n).items())
    states = multiset_partitions_taocp(multiplicities)

    for lst in (factoring_visitor(state, primes) for state in states):
        if len(lst) != 3:
            continue
        lst.sort()
        if sum(lst[:2]) == lst[2]:
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError("no solution found")
    return lst
```